# How can I add favorite list on local storage React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage, use-ref

I want to implement add-to favorite list functionality. But It only works on a single item I need multiple items. I use **useRef** Hook and use this npm package [react-use-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-localstorage)

The problem is my local storage doesn't work properly as I expected. It always updates a single item but I need it as an **Array i.e [1, 2, 4, 7, 10]**

[image]

**If I reload my page only 3 number id will fill the heart**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import FavoriteBorder from "@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorder";
import Favorite from "@mui/icons-material/Favorite";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import useLocalStorage from 'react-use-localstorage';


const Fv = ({ id }) => {
  const [storageItem, setStorageItem] = useLocalStorage(
    "favourites",
    JSON.stringify([])
  );


  //const storagedArray = useRef(JSON.parse(storageItem));
  //const isFavourited = storagedArray.current.includes(id);
  const isFavourited = storageItem.includes(id)



  const handleToggleFavourite = () => {
    if (!isFavourited) {

      setStorageItem(JSON.stringify([...JSON.parse(storageItem), id]));

    } else {

        
      setStorageItem(
        JSON.stringify(
          JSON.parse(storageItem).filter((savedId) => savedId !== id)
        )
      );

    }


  return (
    <IconButton onClick={handleToggleFavourite}>
    {isFavourited ? <Favorite color="error" /> : <FavoriteBorder color="error" />}
  </IconButton>
  );


};

export default Fv;
```

**Assign Component**

```
<Fv id={product.id} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to be perfectly honest, I don't know why your array behaves like that. Maybe it is this external library malfunctioning. You don't need to use any external libraries to manage your `favourites` state. Here is a solution without `react-use-localstorage`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FavoriteBorder from "@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorder";
import Favorite from "@mui/icons-material/Favorite";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";


const Fv = ({ id }) => {
  const [storageItem, setStorageItem] = useState(() => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favourites") || "[]"))

  const isFavourited = storageItem.includes(id)

  const handleToggleFavourite = () => {
    if (!isFavourited) {

      const newStorageItem = [...storageItem, id]
      setStorageItem(newStorageItem);
      localStorage.setItem("favourites", JSON.stringify(newStorageItem))

    } else {

      const newStorageItem = storageItem.filter((savedId) => savedId !== id)
      setStorageItem(newStorageItem);
      localStorage.setItem("favourites", JSON.stringify(newStorageItem))

    }


  return (
    <IconButton onClick={handleToggleFavourite}>
    {isFavourited ? <Favorite color="error" /> : <FavoriteBorder color="error" />}
  </IconButton>
  );


};

export default Fv;
```

Comment: Please give me more details, I try your code I got the error "Fv.js:16 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'c', "current =>"... is not valid JSON"

Comment: Updated my answer, try it now please

Comment: What will be my  `const storagedArray = useRef(JSON.parse(storageItem));
  const isFavourited = storagedArray.current.includes(id);` ?

Comment: `storagedArray` will be `storageItem` and `isFavourited` will be `storageItem.includes(id)`

Comment: Same problem! I have added an image with my question so you can see it better

Comment: I have edited my answer to get rid of `react-use-localstorage` as it is not really necessary, and it may be the root of the problem. So please check the fresh solution without this library.

Comment: It is working but the problem is when I load my page. Array item doesn't add sequence unless I reload my page. I think I should use the useEffect hook but how can I do it?

Comment: So in order for your app to work after you first load it, you need to refresh?

Comment: I need to refresh every time I add a new item to my favorite list. After that, I can add a new item. This way I refresh and add one item after another, but it's not a proper way

Comment: So this means that your component is not updating after invoking `setState` function from `useState` hook. This is very weird behaviour. Could you please put your code somewhere, f.e. on js fiddle so I could take a look?